# Callback com Redux-thunk

Tags: node.js, react, redux

Gostaria de saber como faria para ter um retorno na chamada do *dispath* algo assim, isto com React:

```
this.props.store.dispatch(dados, result => {
   console.log(result);
});
```

Nesta linha acima do `console.log` nunca entra!

**index.js**: (partes relevantes)

```
const reducers = combineReducers({ pacientes, profissional, procedimento });
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

injectTapEventPlugin();

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
..
```

action:

```
export function insertPaciente(paciente, pessoa) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        Axios.callApi('POST', '/pacientes/' + JSON.stringify(paciente) + '/pessoa/' + JSON.stringify(pessoa), {}, pacienteUpdate => {
            dispatch(actionCreator.insertPaciente(pacienteUpdate.id, pacienteUpdate));
            return pacienteUpdate;
        })
    };
}
```

View, onde o método que dispara a action: (partes relevantes)

```
pessoa['datacadastro'] = new Date();
            pessoa['idempresa'] = empresa.getEmpresa();
            paciente['datacadastro'] = new Date();

//Abaixo aqui gostaria de alterar isto ter um callback
this.props.insertPaciente(paciente, pessoa);



const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { pacientes: state.pacientes }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        insertPaciente: (paciente, pessoa) => {
            dispatch(PacienteAction.insertPaciente(paciente, pessoa));
        },

        updatePaciente: (paciente, pessoa) => {
            dispatch(PacienteAction.updatePaciente(paciente, pessoa));
        },
    }
}

PacienteCadastro.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const PacientesContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PacienteCadastro);
export default withStyles(styles)(PacientesContainer);
```

Criei as *actions*, *reducers*, a *store* usando o redux-thunk, enfim tudo como manda o figurino, mas eu não consigo obter o retorno disto.
No *backend* tudo ok, retorna o objeto perfeito, mas não sei como obter o resultado de outra forma, por falta de conhecimento mesmo em redux.
No caso estou fazendo uma tela de cadastro, e ao clicar no botão GRAVAR ele executa a *action*, que efetua o *dispatch*, como disse está tudo ok até ai, mas não sei como pegar o resultado disto!

Comment: Explica melhor a sua estrutura, mostrando o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito simples amigo, oque você precisa fazer é retornar uma `promise` após todas as execuções do seu fluxo.

Primeiro, na sua action, após a requisição e a chamada do `dispatch`, crie uma `promise`. Exemplo:

```
export function insertPaciente(paciente, pessoa) {
  return(dispatch) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)){ // criando a promise
      Axios.callApi('POST', '/pacientes/' + JSON.stringify(paciente) + '/pessoa/' + JSON.stringify(pessoa), {}, pacienteUpdate => {
        dispatch(actionCreator.insertPaciente(pacienteUpdate.id, pacienteUpdate));
        resolve(pacienteUpdate); // chamando o resolve pra ser executado e passando o paciente update
      })
    }
  };
}
```

Depois disso é só você retornar essa `promise` no seu `mapDispatchToProps`. Dessa forma:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    insertPaciente: (paciente, pessoa) => {
      return dispatch(PacienteAction.insertPaciente(paciente, pessoa)); // retornando a promise
    }
  }
}
```

Agora pronto, você pode criar uma função `callback` que vai ser executada depois que requisição for feita e depois que você ter dado um `dispatch`.

```
this.props.insertPaciente(paciente, pessoa)
    .then(response => {
      // Aqui vai a sua função callback, que seria aquele resolve() do seu Action.
    });
```

Espero ter ajudado, bons estudos.

Comment: Muito obrigado vou testar ok. abs.

Comment: Não esquece de dar certo, se essa resposta for a solução do seu problema.

Comment: Novamente obrigado RickPariz, funcionou direitinho só ajustei um erro de sintaxe, no return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { mas excelente! Abs.

Comment: Que ótimo Ceśar, bons estudos.